# Div is moving while resizing page

Tags: html, css

when I zoom my page up to 110%, my div inside the big one becomes bigger and bigger and, after that, it will automatically comes to the new line. Is there any way to prevent it from moving? If yes, help me to fix it and please, don't hate my code.

[Problem shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u81CW.png)

```css
.movieBox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 250px;
}

.mBoxPart {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">
  <div class="movieBox">
    <div class="mBoxPart" style="float: left;">
    </div>
    <div class="mBoxPart" style="width: 80%; ">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quickest solution is to use `display:flex` on container element

**kindly use inline styling with proper reasons**

```css
.movieBox
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex; /* added this */
}

.mBoxPart
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">
  <div class="movieBox">
    <div class="mBoxPart" style="float: left;">
      test
    </div>
    <div class="mBoxPart" style="width: 80%; ">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```